# C# - How to start CATIA with env details

Tags: catia

Hi is it possible to launch Catia by including the env details, with the `exe` path, something like

```
C:\....\bin\cnext.exe -env CATIA_P3.V5-6R2014.B24 -direnv
```

I am able to launch with just the path but would like to know if its possible with the full details as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the properties of the desktop shortcut which launches Catia.  You will see something like this:

```
C....\bin\CATSTART.exe -run "CNEXT.exe" -env ENVNAME -direnv "C:\CATENVIRONMENTS\ENV001"
```

Comment: Yes i see this but i wanted to know how can i include this information to start Catia through code since this info will be in an xml file and i need to extract it to launch catia.